# WebAPI Cookies with ReportViewerWebControl

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, reportviewer

I have an MVC application that also includes an ASP.Net WebForm to host the MS ReportViewer Web Control. We make extensive use of WebAPI to allow for client posting from Knockout viewmodels client side.

In this application, we're making use of cookies to maintain a few minor pieces of user data--a GUID, an int, and a bool.

What we see at present is that the application works correctly until a user opens the ReportViewer.  At that point, we're no longer able to read any cookies from the request headers.  This has been consistently reproduced in several browsers.

Examination with Fiddler has revealed that the cookies are properly posted to the server. In the first case, the cookie value is as follows:

> theCulture=en-US; ASP.NET_SessionId=uhmquapd1bgghpmfgy24oodf; .ASPXAUTH=6BC2F53F9CA0CF5A437998B206B564B28B5AB362153E6E0629C9142F9E3A0285494F674716A126E4632A932BCE12CE094FE590911CE5E97EA42D0C610A44D8462A15BA9A54760883DDF712B5B199C136413667954F094FEBA2A57826BC84702A4D90D7382E360594ABC2F9EBDCEE696B4662077F; special=theId=1077b59a-100d-429b-b223-f8f0508fdc27&staffingId=77096&isBackupUser=False

In the second case, after opening the ReportViewer, our cookies are as follows:

> theCulture=en-US; ASP.NET_SessionId=uhmquapd1bgghpmfgy24oodf; .ASPXAUTH=6BC2F53F9CA0CF5A437998B206B564B28B5AB362153E6E0629C9142F9E3A0285494F674716A126E4632A932BCE12CE094FE590911CE5E97EA42D0C610A44D8462A15BA9A54760883DDF712B5B199C136413667954F094FEBA2A57826BC84702A4D90D7382E360594ABC2F9EBDCEE696B4662077F; special=theId=1077b59a-100d-429b-b223-f8f0508fdc27&staffingId=77096&isBackupUser=False; /Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd%3FOpType%3DSessionKeepAlive%26ControlID%3Dc3b959ab1a7c42e6a9fed5d2762a8c86_SKA=1

At which point we can no longer read them from WebApi.  The method that returns the cookie in the WebAPI Controller is this:

```
public OurType GetApproverInfo()
{ 
    OurType data = new OurType();

    CookieHeaderValue cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("special").FirstOrDefault();
    CookieState cookieState = cookie["special"];

    data.Id = Guid.Parse(cookieState["theId"]);
    data.StaffingId = Int32.Parse(cookieState["staffingId"]);
    data.IsBackupUser = bool.Parse(cookieState["isBackupUser"]);

    return data;
}
```

Anyone else seen something like this?

**UPDATE:** I've just learned that creating a cookie with a leading / in the name causes the same behavior in WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that the **ReportView** is messing up the **cookie**. Probably you're setting up the **cookie** somewhere in the `WebApi` that has not the same pipeline execution sequence as the `ReportView Handle`.

Heres the WebApi life cycle: [ASP.NET WEB API: HTTP MESSAGE LIFECYLE](http://www.asp.net/posters/web-api/ASP.NET-Web-API-Poster.pdf)

But, you can override the **ReportViewerServerConnection**, using `IReportServerConnection`, and there persist yours **cookie** pattern.

Take a look here: [Web.config Settings for ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251661.)

Another way should be setting up the **cookie** in a Custom `IHttpModule`, integrated into the ASP.NET pipe line, and then target both, `WebApi` and `ReportView`